# How to Individual selection?

Tags: react-native

I'd like to make the entire selection into individual choices in the process of using the map method. But I don't know how.

My code:

```
  let bouncyCheckboxRef = null;
  const [bodyType, setBodyType] = useState([]);
  const [standardSelected, setStandardSelected] = useState(false);
  const [isSelected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const bodyGetData = async () => {
    let body = [];
    try {
      let config = {
        method: "get",
        url:
          "http://everyweardev-env.eba-azpdvh2m.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/v1/user/bodyType/female",
        headers: {},
      };

      axios(config).then(function (response) {
        response.data.data.map((u) => {
          switch (u.bodyType) {
            case "standard":
              body.push({
                bodyType: "스탠다드",
                imgUrl: u.imgUrl,
                key: 1,
                isChecked: true,
              });
              break;
            case "reverseTriangle":
              body.push({
                bodyType: "역삼각형",
                imgUrl: u.imgUrl,
                key: 2,
                isChecked: true,
              });
              break;
            case "triangle":
              body.push({
                bodyType: "삼각형",
                imgUrl: u.imgUrl,
                key: 3,
                isChecked: true,
              });
              break;
            case "circle":
              body.push({
                bodyType: "원형",
                imgUrl: u.imgUrl,
                key: 4,
                isChecked: true,
              });
              break;
            case "hourglass":
              body.push({
                bodyType: "직사각형",
                imgUrl: u.imgUrl,
                key: 5,
                isChecked: true,
              });
              break;
          }
        });
        return setBodyType(body);
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
      bodyGetData();
    });
    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);
  const checkBoxChange = (checked) => {
    let newCheckBoxes = [...bodyType];
    newCheckBoxes.forEach((item) => {
      if (item.key) {
        item.isChecked = checked;
      }
    });
    setBodyType(newCheckBoxes);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text
        style={{ fontSize: wp("5.5%"), fontWeight: "bold", marginBottom: 21 }}
      >
        자신의 체형을 선택해 주세요
      </Text>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", marginBottom: hp("10%") }}>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: wp("4.5%"), marginRight: wp("1%") }}>
          더 정확한 평가를 받으실 수 있습니다
        </Text>
        <Image
          source={require("../../images/smile.png")}
          style={{ marginTop: hp("0.5%") }}
        />
      </View>
      <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={true}>
        {bodyType.map((data) => (
          <>
            <TouchableHighlight
              style={styles.bodySelect}
              value={data.bodyType}
              onChange={(e) => {
                console.log(e);
              }}
              onPress={() => bouncyCheckboxRef?.onPress()}
            >
              <>
                <BouncyCheckbox
                  checked={data.isChecked}
                  key={data.key}
                  onPress={checkBoxChange}
                  ref={(ref) => (bouncyCheckboxRef = ref)}
                  size={25}
                  fillColor="black"
                  unfillColor="#FFFFFF"
                  iconStyle={{ borderColor: "white" }}
                  textStyle={{ fontFamily: "JosefinSans-Regular" }}
                  disableBuiltInState
                  style={{
                    alignSelf: "flex-start",
                    marginLeft: wp("3%"),
                    marginTop: hp("2%"),
                  }}
                />
                <SvgCssUri
                  uri={data.imgUrl}
                  width="90%"
                  height="60%"
                  marginTop="-5%"
                  key={data.key}
                />
                <Text style={styles.bodytype}>{data.bodyType}</Text>
              </>
            </TouchableHighlight>
          </>
        ))}
      </ScrollView>
      <TouchableHighlight
        style={styles.button}
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate("얼굴형 정보 입력");
        }}
        underlayColor="gray"
      >
        <>
          <Text style={styles.text}>선택 완료</Text>
        </>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where do you hold the isSelected data? Can you post your entire code?

Comment: I uploaded the entire code. Help me. I don't know what to do.

Comment: I modified the code again.Help me. I don't know what to do